# single quotes and double quotes in mysql insert and update query (java)

Tags: java, mysql, escaping

The ComName is 'a'b'c'"def"j Limited.

i try to add \ before every ' and " but the resultant query that is executed is

```
"UPDATE empTable SET empId= '25', ComName = 'a'b'c'"def"j Limited  where ID=1"
```

i don't see my Comname within '' and \ is not present before every ' and "

Here is the code to construct the column value

```
columnValue.replaceAll("\'", "\\" + "\'");
columnValue.replaceAll("\"", "\\" + "\"");
columnValue=("'" + columnValue + "'");
```

How to insert string of these types?

Comment: Yes, you *must* use PreparedStatement for this, everything else is just crying out for a SQL Injection attack. But appart from that, you should rememeber that a `replaceAll()` call is only ever useful, if you do something with the return value. Strings are immutable, so ignoring the newly returned `String` that contains the new value means you didn't actually do anything in that line.

Comment: i understand that return string is important here and i use it correctly the problem is with quotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as quick fix you can try using Apache commons lang [StringEscapeUtils#escapeSql](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)) or equivalent library such as [this one](http://ostermiller.org/utils/doc/com/Ostermiller/util/StringHelper.html)

Comment: use only as a quick fix, prepared statements are far better

Comment: i understand, yet deadline, project phase plays a vital role too :)

Comment: It only escapes single quotes - `StringUtils.replace(str, "'", "''")`

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [PreparedStatements](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in the JDBC library. e.g.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update Orders set pname = ? where Prod_Id = ?");
pstmt.setInt(2, 100);
pstmt.setString(1, "Bob");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

By using [setString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) etc. it will save you from having to quote strings. [Here's a tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on how to use them.

EDIT: As Nick has highlighted below, this will save you not just from quoting issues, but from SQL injection (security) issues as well.

Comment: +1 - there are hundreds of articles why escaping yourself doesn't just introduce bugs but security flaws

Comment: The realtime problem here is the column name , table name all are dynamic :( It will really hard to find the correct column order and data type